# Jquery change when JS variable changes not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a game where you click a button to earn a point. Once you obtain X amount of points a div appears. I tired using jquery's .change to see if #pointCounter has changed in order to know if the new div should appear (by adding the new class). This isn't working though. Am I not using the change method correctly, or should I use something else? Is there a to check when the var points changes instead of checking if the html changes?

HTML

```
 <p>You have <span id='pointCounter'>0</span> points.</p>
 <button id='clickButton'>Click Me</button>
 <div id='store'></div>
```

JS

```
$('#clickButton').click(function() {
  points = points + addPoints;
  $('#pointCounter').html(points);
});


$('#pointCounter').change(function() {
  if (points >= 5) {
    $('#store').addClass('showMe');
 }
});
```

Comment: If you read the documentation on .change() you'll see it only works on "<input> elements, <textarea> boxes and <select> elements." Just put the code you have in your change function in the click function.

Comment: where is the initial value for points set and where is addPoints set? I dont see anywhere where the value of points changes so there is nothing to trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Is it not possible to display the div at this point:

```
$('#clickButton').click(function() {
  points = points + addPoints;
  if (points > 500) $('#someDIV').addClass('showme');
  $('#pointCounter').html(points);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change is just for selects or other form elements as j08691 said but you could do something like this, right now I just have points set as a global var but you could also pass a value into the function to increment the points value.

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/1j33tm0g/1/

```
var points = 0;
var addPoints = 1;

$('#clickButton').click(function() {
  points += addPoints;
  $('#pointCounter').html(points);
    if(points >= 5) {
       $('#store').addClass('showMe');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with jQuery hide/show:

```
<p>You have <span id='pointCounter'>0</span> points.</p>
 <button id='clickButton'>Click Me</button>
 <div id='store'>Test</div>
```

And using the JS:

```
var points = 0;
var addPoints = 1;

$("#store").hide();

$('#clickButton').click(function() {
  points = points + addPoints;
  $('#pointCounter').html(points);
  if (points >= 5) {
    $('#store').show();
  }
});
```

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/rnm9e5vh/